# SDL library couldn't be found in cmake

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake

I am trying to write a cmake.I will use OpenGL, SDL and OpenCV together. The things is cmake operation is done properly but if I enter make command, it says that "No such file or directory" for SDL/SDL.h

my cmake is like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

project (VisionTest)

# compiler version checking does not work if CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER is not set
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpversion
                    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
    message("GCC version: ${GCC_VERSION}")
    if (GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "5.0.0" OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL "5.0.0")
            message(STATUS "GCC version >= 5.0, use CXX11_ABI=1")
    else()
        add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
    endif()
endif()

find_package(OpenCV)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

add_executable(
    VisionTest
    src/arucoDetect.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(VisionTest ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${SDL2_LIBRARY} 
    ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

In the source code my includes are:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/shape.hpp"
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>

#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <algorithm>

#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
```

as last, my directory structure for the project is:

```
CMakeCache.txt  Makefile   camera_calibration.cpp  paths.cmake
CMakeLists.txt  README.md  cmake_install.cmake     src

./src:
arucoDetect.cpp
```

and paths.cmake as a guidance, I took it from my friend for the same project(but complex one):

```
# define platform specific paths in this file
SET(TOOLCHAIN_DIR "/opt" CACHE STRING "")

include(cmake/TargetArch.cmake)
target_architecture(ARCH)
MESSAGE("TOOLCHAIN_DIR is set to:  ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}")
MESSAGE("BUILDING FOR:  ${ARCH}")

#include target specific linker and include_directories
IF(${ARCH} MATCHES "aarch64")

    set(QT5_DIR ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/qt5-odroid)

    set(ZEROMQ_INCLUDE_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/zeromq-odroid/include)
    set(ZEROMQ_LIB_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/zeromq-odroid/lib)

    set(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/protobuf-odroid/include)
    set(PROTOBUF_LIB_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/protobuf-odroid/lib)
    set(PROTOBUF_PROTOC ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/protobuf-host/bin/protoc)

    set(LIBSODIUM_LIB_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/libsodium-odroid/lib)

    set(OpenCV_DIR ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/opencv-odroid/share/OpenCV/)
ELSEIF(${ARCH} MATCHES "x86_64")
    set(QT5_DIR ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/qt5-host)

    set(ZEROMQ_INCLUDE_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/zeromq-host/include)
    set(ZEROMQ_LIB_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/zeromq-host/lib)

    set(PROTOBUF_INCLUDE_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/protobuf-host/include)
    set(PROTOBUF_LIB_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/protobuf-host/lib)
    set(PROTOBUF_PROTOC ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/protobuf-host/bin/protoc)

    set(LIBSODIUM_LIB_PATH ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/libsodium-host/lib)

    set(OpenCV_DIR ${TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/opencv-host/share/OpenCV/)
ENDIF(${ARCH} MATCHES "aarch64")

# set Qt CMake paths
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${QT5_DIR}/lib/cmake)
set(Qt5Core_DIR ${QT5_DIR}/lib/cmake/Qt5Core)
set(Qt5Scxml_DIR ${QT5_DIR}/lib/cmake/Qt5Scxml)
set(Qt5Qml_DIR ${QT5_DIR}/lib/cmake/Qt5Qml)
set(Qt5Network_DIR ${QT5_DIR}/lib/cmake/Qt5Network)
set(Qt5Test_DIR ${QT5_DIR}/lib/cmake/Qt5Test)

MESSAGE("CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is set to:  ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
MESSAGE("Qt5Core_DIR is set to:  ${Qt5Core_DIR}")
MESSAGE("Qt5Scxml_DIR is set to:  ${Qt5Scxml_DIR}")
MESSAGE("Qt5Qml_DIR is set to:  ${Qt5Qml_DIR}")
MESSAGE("Qt5Network_DIR is set to:  ${Qt5Network_DIR}")
MESSAGE("Qt5Test_DIR is set to:  ${Qt5Test_DIR}")
```

I am just starting to use cmake so I couldn't find anything to use properly. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Perhaps the most obvious question first: Is there a file such as `SDL/SDL.h` under `$SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS` ?

Comment: I think I got what you mean. I changed to library to SDL to SDL2 and it worked. With additional errors. I think I have sdl2 but not sdl1. And I am trying to use the second one while coding with first version. Thanks for the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Marco A. I found the problem. I use SDL for the code and I tried to include SDL2. I installed sdl1.2 and added SDL binding. To install SDL:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2-dev
```

and new cmake is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.2)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

project (VisionTest)

# compiler version checking does not work if CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER is not set
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER)
    execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -dumpversion
                    OUTPUT_VARIABLE GCC_VERSION)
    message("GCC version: ${GCC_VERSION}")
    if (GCC_VERSION VERSION_GREATER "5.0.0" OR GCC_VERSION VERSION_EQUAL "5.0.0")
            message(STATUS "GCC version >= 5.0, use CXX11_ABI=1")
    else()
        add_definitions(-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0)
    endif()
endif()

find_package(OpenCV)
find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(
    ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR}
    ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS}
    )

add_executable(
    VisionTest
    src/arucoDetect.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(VisionTest ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${SDL2_LIBRARY} 
    ${SDL_LIBRARY} 
    ${GLEW_LIBRARIES}
    ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
    )
```